# Linking button controls to data (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, controls

I am working on an application showing 20 graphic buttons controls in a MainWindow (Button1 to Button20).
Each button control can display a Content string, and has a tooltip designed as follow :

```
<Button x:Name="button1" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Height="29" Click="Button_Click" Background="#FFFFFFFF" MouseEnter="button_MouseEnter">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <Border Margin="-4,0,-4,-3" Padding="10" Background="Yellow">
                <Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect></OuterGlowBitmapEffect>
                </Border.BitmapEffect>
                <Label x:Name ="lbl1" FontSize="20" Content="{Binding Path=ToolTip}">
                </Label>
            </Border>
        </Button.ToolTip>
        <Button.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </Button.Effect>
    </Button>
```

I would like to define the string content and the tooltip string for each button in an XML file so this information can be changed by modifying the XML file.

For this, I created a ViewModel defining an object called Bouton (in french) :

```
public class Bouton : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    int boutonNumber;
    public int BoutonNumber{ get { return boutonNumber; } set { boutonNumber= value; Notify("BoutonNumber"); } }
    string texteBouton;
    public string TexteBouton { get { return texteBouton; } set { texteBouton = value; Notify("TexteBouton"); } }
    string tooltip;
    public string Tooltip { get { return tooltip; } set { tooltip = value; Notify("ToolTip"); } }
    public Bouton(int nb, string tb, string tt)
    {
        BoutonNumber = nb;
        TexteBouton = tb;
        Tooltip = tt;
    }
}
```

When reading the XML file, I create 20 objects of Bouton type with the information about boutonNumber, Content and Tooltip. Then all these Bouton objects are stored into a List collection.

Now I want to use DataBinding between my Bouton list and the graphic controls on my MainWindow to be able to display the content string and the tooltip string on each button.
In the MainWindow, I used the following code :

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Bouton> lst = Utilities.CreateList();
        this.DataContext = lst;
    }
```

where lst is a List collection correctly initialized.

But I do not know how to make the databinding work on the Button controls. How can I make each of the 20 Button controls correctly link to the corresponding Bouton object (contained in the Boutons collection) ? I mean how can Button1 control get its strings from my Bouton1 object, the Button2 control get its string from Bouton2 object and so on until Button20 control and Bouton20 object ?

Thank you for your help. Please note I am a beginner with WPF and this is my first WPF project with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest option would be to wrap your button in a UserControl.

This UserControl then contains a property of type `Bouton` *(not great naming btw. - even if it is a different language, the term "button" already exists, so this is rather ambiguous. As a non-native english speaker myself, I also recommend getting used to naming in English, it will save you lots of headaches in the long run, but that might be subjective )*

You can then bind directly to that property in the UserControl's template. All you have to do is assign each UserControl the correct button data.

eg.

```
public class CustomButton : UserControl
{
    public Bouton ParsedButtonData { get; set; }

    public CustomButton()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and in your UserControl's template:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <Border ...>
            <Label Content="{Binding ParsedButtonData.Tooltip}" ...>
            </Label>
        </Border>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

You can then place the UserControl in your XAML like this:

`xmlns:ctrls="clr-namespace:MyProject.MyNamespace"`

`<ctrls:CustomButton name="myFirstButton"/>`

Now all you have to do is make sure each CustomButton has their ParsedButtonData set to the corresponding piece of data. You can either set this manually for each button created in your XAML, or you can create the CustomButtons through C# in the first place.

If you create your UserControls in XAML, for example:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    myFirstButton.ParsedButtonData = lst[0];
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to look into extending `ItemsControl`. It's basically made for this sort of application. An ItemsControl has an ItemsSource, which can be any collection type such as `List<>` or `ObservableCollection<>`. It then creates its children from that collection, setting the DataContext automatically to the corresponding element in said list.

Examples of that would be `DataGrid` or `ListView`. I find that to be a little more involved though, if you really just want to place a bunch of a Buttons on a single View.

Comment: I really appreciate your interest for my question,  your answer and the details of code you gave in it. I will give it a try as soon as possible. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I tried this code yesterday. I still have some questions : I made the class CustomButton inheritate from Button (rather than from UserControl as you suggested) but I have an error message about Click event which is said not to be present in the CustomButton class. I am surprised since the base class (Button) has the Click event implemented. I tried to call base.Click() from the CustomButton but I still get an error message. I don't understand why Click event does not exist in CustomButton, as it does exist in Button class.

Comment: Why don't you use a UserControl instead of inheriting from Button? In a UserControl, you an easily register a click event for any button you place in the template.

Comment: Ok i will try this. Thank you.